# Notepad ++ Find and delete after =

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a text file in this format

```
abc1=kdkaf
def2 = lakdfjads
aa3 =kdkakdfadsf
2323= kakdfadf
```

In Notepad++ I want to find and delete all the data after **=** 
so that I can only have:

```
abc1
def2 
aa3 
2323
```

Comment: can I ask why you give me -1 ?

Comment: because you are asking for user guidance on a specific software product. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: @niceguy our answer does help you , you need more informations ?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken I can give you links of stack overflow where similar questions are asked and Notepad ++ is also mentioned.

Comment: @VERYNET Thanks a lot your answer is very helpful

Comment: @niceguy sorry, but that is not a valid argument. Because someone else does something wrong, it does not entitle you to do so as well :).

Comment: @JanusVarmarken the only thing that is bugging me, that the guy asked the same question got like +3. 
And I got -2 for asking the same kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search mode regular expression

```
[=].*
```

Replace with nothing.

It searches for "=" , followed by any character (.) any number of times (*), effectively "any sequence of characters", ending at the line break.

Comment: this will not include the spaces before `=` in selected string

Comment: you don't need to use `[=]` since `=` is not a special character

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
=.*
```

With a empty replacement string

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have alphabets only after the `=`， Try

```
\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z]*
```

Or this if you want to include CrLf too

```
\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z]*\r\n
```

After selecting 'Regular expression' in Search Mode